# How convert byte to decimal?

Tags: vb.net, hex

Please guide me how make convert that input to decimal.tq.

```
BF C2 FF 12 
65 E4 EE 
17 BF C2 64 F2 41 84 11 
C1 C4 38 41 14 10 C1 04 10 49 04 18 41 06 72 B5 FF 
17 BF C2 64 72 
41 84 11 C1 85 19 C1 07 17 7D C2 5F 3D 5E FD DE 57 FD 10 E1 94 30 B5 FF 
17 BF C2 FF 12 
65 CC 76 
17 BF C2 FF 12 
69 FC 77
```

Comment: Hex to decimal conversion (and vice versa) is one of the more fundamental concepts to understand. If you can do binary conversions, then rather than base-2, think base-16. The concept beyond that is identical. Google for hex to decimal conversion, or read up about hexadecimal/base-16 on Wikipedia.

Comment: tq=thank you .Thank you Heinzi

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows open up the calculator and go to view scientific.  Then you can convert small pieces of your code one group at a time.

To do it by hand you divide by 16 until you get zero and then you combine the remainders.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us your input and wanted output format.
I assumed you have the data in a String variable named "input" and want it as byte array.

```
Dim input As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\data.txt")
Dim output As Byte() = input.Split(" ").Select(Function(b) Convert.ToByte(b, 16)).ToArray
```

Edit:

```
For Each part As String In IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\data.txt").Split(" ")
    If part.Trim.Length > 0 Then
        Dim number As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(part, 16)
        Console.Write(number & ",")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: i have this data at C:\data.txt

Comment: Okay fixed that. Output is still Byte() because you said nothing about that.

Comment: input at C:\data.txt, and i wat output as console

Comment: ouch... output as decimal ,input as byte.tq David R

Comment: My guess is you are using a version of VB.NET prior to 2008.
I have rewritten the code and it should work now.

Comment: If your question is solved now you should flag the answer that best helped you as answer to your question.

Comment: i vote for second solution, but it's still get error unhandled exception.I'm using vb.net 2005 .I need change to 2008 version or not?

Comment: How open port such as COM1,COM2,COM3 or COM4?That data than convert from hex to decimal and showed using console.writeline?

Comment: Unhandled Exception is not enough information. You need to help us helping you. Long time since I last used 2005. You should update if possible. I have rewritten the code with less advanced features compatible with old versions.
regarding COM you should open a new question cause that has nothing to do with convert byte/decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim input As String = "BF C2 FF 12 65 E4 EE 17 BF C2 64 [...]"
For Each s As String In input.Split(" "c)
    Dim value As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16)
    Console.Write(value & " ")    ' Or whatever else you want to do with the converted data
Next
```

Comment: what type of c? integer or char?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `" "c` means: space character (`' '` in C#), as opposed to `" "`, which would mean: string containing a space (`" "` in C#).

Comment: To clarify: The `c` in `" "c` is not a variable but rather a syntactic element (a *literal type character*), see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Dim value = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16) 
got unhandled exception message.

Comment: Me declared s as Byte.it's ok or not?

Comment: Then you have some stuff in your input that is not a hexadecimal number, or you have more separators than just space. Wrap the inner part of the loop into a `Try...Catch` block and output an error message including the `s` that caused the trouble. This will help you find the culprit.

Comment: @Mohd: No, `s` is a String. Since you are apparently not using `Option Infer`, I will add some type declaration to my example...

Comment: it work now, but got message unhandled exception after console write launch.